# How to add table model values by editing JTable rows?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have empty TableModel. When I set this model to JTable it hasn't rows. I want to create one empty row, where user can select value in combo box editor. If user selects not-null value, then second row added and I have one object in model. How can I add empty row, when there is not object for this row in model?

Comment: Can't you just add a row to the TableModel? Maybe you should post some code because this question isn't entirely clear. And take a look at an implementation of TableModel called [DefaultTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow(java.lang.Object[])).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TableModel is your friend: implement it's setValueAt method to add a row after setting the value. Here's an example for doing so by subclassing DefaultTableModel:

```
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(1, 3) {

        /** 
         * @inherited <p>
         */
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
            super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
            if (shouldAddRow(row, column)) {
                addRow(new Object[] {});
            }
        }

        private boolean shouldAddRow(int lastEditedRow, int lastEditedColumn) {
            // implement your logic here
            return lastEditedRow == getRowCount() -1;
        }


    };
```

Comment: @mKorbel that was pure lazyness (as you know, I'm not a big fan of subclassing :-) - doing the same in a TableModelListener would have implied to correctly detangle the "update" from the given TableModelEvent, which I hate to do without SwingX TableUtils at hand

Comment: agreed with that confortly simplify and pretty restict this magic box :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
I want to create one empty row, where user can select value in combo box editor.
```

that isn't empty row,

you can add null value to the JTable Cell, more in the tutorial about [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [JComboBox as an Editor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox), and examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm)

Comment: the values of the TableModel might well be empty (aka: return null values) - at that moment only the combo's popup has values != null (if I understand the OP correctly, not much to go on :-)